# How to store list of list to h5 file in python

Tags: python, h5py

I have this:

```
data = [array([[ 0.5129556,  0.4993599,  0.5027999,  0.5005983]]), 
array([[ 0.5129556,  0.4993599,  0.5027999,  0.5005983,  
0.4979439, 0.4991087,  0.4982641]])]

name ='name'

filename = 'path'
```

I want to write this to a H5 file from python. I am getting the following error:

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (4) into 
shape (1)
```

What I currently have is this:

```
 with h5py.File(filename, 'w') as hf:
        for i in data:
           hf.create_dataset(name = name, data=data, 
                            shape=len(data), dtype=float)
```

Comment: I suggest you quickly format this blob for better reading...

Comment: I think your iteration idea is right - just need to correct the definition of `name` and the `data` that is saved for each name.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that your data array has variable-length rows. Do you want to write the entire `data` to a single dataset or do you want to write each row of the data to a different dataset? In the first case you need to fix your data array to have equal length rows (and the loop in your code makes no sense) and in the latter case you need to fix the dataset name (i.e., provide a unique `name` for each row) and set `data=i` (`i` in your code and `d` in my code below):

```
with h5py.File(filename, 'w') as hf:
    for n, d in enumerate(data):
        hf.create_dataset(name = 'dataset{:d}'.format(n), data=d)
```